# Implementing Stream in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I want to implement a stream object that can do this:

```
// a -------1------2----3
// map -----\------\----\
// b --------2------4----6

const a = new Stream();
const b = a.map(value => value * 2);

b.subscribe(console.log);

a.push(1);
// 2
a.push(2);
// 4
a.push(3);
// 6
```

The idea here is that the object `b` can subscribe new callbacks to stream `a`. The `map` function should listen when `push` is called and apply the mapped out function as well as the originally subscribed one. This is the implementation I have so far:

```
class Stream {
  constructor(queue = []) {
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  subscribe(action) {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      this.queue.push(action);
    }
  }

  map(callback) {
     this.queue = this.queue.map(
        actionFn => arg => action(callback(arg))
     );

     return this;
  }

  push(value) {
    this.queue.forEach(actionFn => {
      actionFn.call(this, value);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem with current implementation is that originally the `queue` in class `Stream` is empty so it doesn't go through it. Would appreciate any suggestions or help. I would like to not use any library for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your map needs to create a new `Transform` stream and return it. Instead of the `subscribe` you could simply use the standard `on('data')` event or, better use the `read` method.

Lastly - you could simply use my work and have your `map` method already efficiently implemented by using [`scramjet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet), which does exactly what you shown above - and moreover it supports async functions. :)

Here's how you'd use it (in some `getStream` function):

```
const {DataStream} = require('scramjet');

const stream = new DataStream();

stream.write(1); // you can also use await stream.whenWrote(1);
stream.write(2);
stream.write(3);

return stream.map(x => x * 2);
```

and then read it somewhere else:

```
stream.on('data', x => console.log(`x: ${x}`));
// x: 2
// x: 4
// x: 6
```

Take a look at the [scramjet docs](https://scramjet.eu) here

Answer (score 0):

After such a long time of asking this question I was able to go back to the problem and come up with a simple solution. Since one stream should listen to the one it is subscribed to, we should return the instance of the original in order to preserve the values from the previous stream. Here is the code that I found to be working well:

```js
class Stream {
    constructor() {
        this.subscriptions = [];
        this.mappedActions = [];
    }

    subscribe(callback) {
        this.subscriptions.push(callback);
    }

    map(actionFunc) {
        this.mappedActions.push(actionFunc);

        return this;
    }

    push(opValue) {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(cb => {
            if (this.mappedActions.length) {
                this.mappedActions.forEach(action => {
                    cb(action.call(this, opValue));
                });
            } else {
                cb(opValue);
            }
        });
    }
}

const a = new Stream();
const b = a.map(value => value * 1 / 2);
const c = b.map(value => value * 3);

c.subscribe(console.log);

c.push(1);
c.push(2);
c.push(3);

// expected output in the console:
// 0.5
// 3
// 1
// 6
// 1.5
// 9
```

Hope anyone who stumbles upon this interesting problem will find my solution useful. If there is any changes you would like to make, feel free to do so or ping me!